# Kaam is one of Prusarth but In Gita Krishna consider it as gateway to hell . How?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, purushartha

Kaam is of 4 Purusarth namely Dharma ,Artha , **Kaam** and Moksha.

Gita 16:21

> There are three gateways to the hell of self-destruction for the soul. These are **Kaam**, anger, and greed. Therefore one should **abandon these three completely**.

Krishna says to abandon Kaam completely.
If we abandon it completely , then how it is purusarth.
And if it is Purusarth , then how it leads to hell ?

Comment: The meaning of word Kaam is contextual based on what is referred in the whole passage..  there numerous words like that even in english sens it can only equated to desire. Now based on this sloka context Krishna meant only sexual desire.. will lead to hell not the desire of having mokshaa or seeking lords feet..

Comment: i can you all the four in different context. 1. Duryodhana dharma is to cheat 2. Misers Artha is like sowing seed in waste land 3. Thieves got moksha from the prison.  ( 1. Dhrama is used for Adharma 2. Artha is used wrong wealth 3.  moksha is used to mean relieve)

Comment: This is due to limitations of Sanskrit vocabulary.  Kama is neutral to positive - negative words appropriate here would be lust, carnality, lasciviousness, lechery, lewdness,, ,licentiousness, prurience, salaciousness

Comment: @SK How do you say it's a limitation . Can you substantiate? Are you any niruktha/linguistics expert ?

Comment: just common sense. a purushartha cannot be a gateway to hell.   sanskrit equivalent of a word from the list I provided above would have been be better to depict as a gateway to hell. @athrey .

Comment: whatever be the opinion, pronouncing it as a limitation of a language, require lot of analysis . well an expert may opine it to be feature@SK

Comment: "lechery" is the most appropriate word that would lead to hell - but the dictionary gives only relatively unknown equivalents in Sanskrit 1 कटार (lecher)2 खेटिन् (lecher) 3 लम्पट (lecher) @athrey

Comment: As far as I ve come to know , purusha connotes human and Artha connotes seeking . So purushartha (falls in the category of 4)is what is sought after by humans. So connotation in general may not necessarily mean limitation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If Narayana is father of Kaama, then why should we disregard lust, sex, et cetera?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18267/if-narayana-is-father-of-kaama-then-why-should-we-disregard-lust-sex-et-ceter)

Answer (score 2):

You have misread the verses probably.

Let's start with the Sanskrit Verses.

> चिन्तामपरिमेयां च प्रलयान्तामुपाश्रिताः ।
>  कामोपभोग**परमा** ।
>
> एतावदिति निश्िचताः ॥ 16.11 ॥
>
> > 11 Giving themselves over to immeasurable cares ending only with death, regarding gratification of lust as their **highest aim**, and feeling sure that that is all.
>
> English Translation by Swami Sivananda

**The keyword is 'paramā (परमा)'.**

So, Sri Krishna is admonishing those people who tend to think that "*the enjoyment of desirable objects, sense gratification, lust etc, as the highest human goal*".

Let's see this in the light of commentary by some preceptors -

> [English Commentary](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=16&field_nsutra_value=11&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1) By Swami Sivananda
>
> They are beset with immense cares? worries and anxieties and their
> minds are engrossed in aciring and preserving the countless sensual
> objects. **They have got the strong conviction that the sensual
> enjoyment is the highest end of a man. They are steeped in enjoying
> the objects of the senses. They firmly believe that that is
> everything. They believe that sensual enjoyment is the supreme source
> of happiness and there is no such thing as eternal bliss of the soul
> or transcendental bliss of the Self.** They have no belief in the
> happiness in another world (or plane) or in the perennial bliss which
> is independent of sensual objects? which is beyond the reach of the
> senses. They have a dull and gross intellect? and so they cannot grasp
> the subtle higher truth. Sensual enjoyment is the greatest object of
> attainment for them.

Thus people who give-in to their evil resolutions and desires, which only end in death; and those who seek only the gratification of desire as the highest goal; seeing nothing beyond that - it's those ilk being chastised here, not the puruṣārtha of Kāma.

The god is not demonizing the four Puruṣārthas that are based on Dharma. As I already discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51173/17833)

> यस्मिन् धर्मसमायुक्तावर्थकामौ व्यवस्थितौ इह लोके सुखी भूत्वा
> प्रेत्यानन्त्याय कल्पते ॥ २.५५ ॥
>
> > A person, in whom Artha and Kāma live side by side supported by
> > Dharma, becomes happy in this world and becomes entitled to infinite
> > nature (eternal salvation) after death.
>
> Kurma Purāṇa I.2.55

**To conclude -**

So the Puruṣārthas of Kāma and Artha aren't to be abandoned, they're to be practised in  the dharmika ways only, with faith and belief in the almighty.

Answer (score 0):

Lust has to be abandoned completely for people who are struggling for moksha. Kama as purushartha is not a license for sexual pleasure but to keep the human race alive.

**Dharma**

> Dharma, understood as the Supreme Good of man, can never have wealth
> as its reward. Nor has wealth, understood as an aid to the achievement
> of Dharma, been conceived as an aid for the attainment of kama (sexual
> desire). **Kama in its turn is not a call to indulgence in sexual
> pleasures, but a mere inducement implanted by the Creator to make life
> unbroken.** And as for life, it has the quest of the Supreme Truth as
> its end – not certainly Karma (i.e. performance of rituals and social
> duties) for the attainment of wealth (prosperity here and heaven
> hereafter).

Srimad Bhagavata Purana I.2.9-10